# Does $\frac{1} { ax+b}$ apply when $b$ equals $0$

Tags: integration

This is a dumb question but I'd still like to confirm it here, I just haven't found any information about this in internet.

According to any table of integrals $\int \frac{1}{ax+b} \, dx = \frac{1}{a} \ln(ax+b)$ . This doesn't work if if $b=0$, right? Because $\int\frac{1}{ax} \, dx$ should equal to $\frac{1}{a} \int \frac{1}{x} \, dx$ which would be $\frac{1}{a} \ln(x)$.

Comment: Try taking the derivative of the function you expect to be the answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It still works, your result is the same as $\tfrac1a\ln(ax)$, *up to a constant*. Note that, $$\tfrac1a\ln(ax)=\tfrac1a(\ln a+\ln x)=\tfrac{\ln a}a+\tfrac1a\ln x.$$